# How to implement custom ordering for data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, ord

Let's say I have a data type that represents a deck of poker cards like so

```
data Suit = Clubs | Spades | Hearts | Diamonds deriving (Eq)

instance Show Suit where
    show Diamonds = "♦"
    show Hearts = "♥"
    show Spades = "♠"
    show Clubs = "♣"

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card {
      value :: Value
    , suit :: Suit
    } deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

instance Show Card where
    show (Card v s) = show s ++ show v

Haskell helps me already a lot by allow me to derive `Eq` and `Ord` without explicitly specifying those relations.
This is especially useful, because I want to use `Ord` to ultimately compare the value of two hands according to Poker rules.

Now in Poker, the suits do not really matter in terms of ordering. Therefore I tried

```
instance Ord Suit where
    compare Clubs Spades = EQ
    compare Clubs Hearts = EQ
    compare Clubs Diamonds = EQ
    compare Spades Hearts = EQ
    compare Spades Diamonds = EQ
    compare Hearts Diamonds = EQ
```

This is already a bit verbose ... and it does not even work:

```
*P054> a
♠A
*P054> b
♣A
*P054> a < b
*** Exception: P054.hs:(12,9)-(17,36): Non-exhaustive patterns in function compare
```

So how can I properly define an ordering on `Suit` that expresses the fact that all suits are equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing several combinations, e.g. all with `Clubs` on the right hand side. If all are equal, what are the possible results of `compare`, regardless of the input? There is only one: `EQ`. Therefore we don't even need to look at `a` or `b`:

```
instance Ord Suit where
    compare _ _ = EQ
```

However, that `Ord` instance is rather useless. Alternatively you can create a custom instance for `Card`,

```
instance Ord Card where
    compare a b = compare (value a) (value b)
    -- compare = compare `on` value -- using `on` from Data.Function
    -- compare = comparing value    -- using `comparing` from Data.Ord
```

Comment: Defining an instance like that is probably bad design. Not many people would expect that an `Ord` instance would be defined as `const (const EQ)`. If a comparison between Suits doesn't make sense, the Ord instance should simply not exist. If suit does not affect the ordering of a card, as OP said, then the Ord instance for *Card* should simply ignore the suit: `compare = Data.Ord.comparing val`

Comment: @user2407038 I would accept your comment as an answer.